# Email Certificate Export Wizard is not allowing me to export Private Key

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, encryption, certificate, export

I have a few email certificates, stored on an older computer, that I would like to Import onto my newer computer.

I have headed over to `certmgr.msc`, where I have identified the relevant Email Certificates.  I then proceeded to Export the Email Certificate by heading to:

- Action > Export > All Tasks > Export.

Upon going through the Export Wizard, I am met with the notice:

> Note: The associated private key is marked as not exportable.  Only
>   the certificate can be exported.

Obviously, I need the Private Key too.

Is there any way around this?  The email certificate provider was acquired by another company, who are refusing to assist with the matter.

I am not sure if this affects anything but I can see that I am able to export the Private Key on all expired Email Certificates just not for the Valid Email Certificates.

Comment: certmgr.msc is all about local user store, you could try looking in the local computer store using certlm.msc

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion.  Unfortunately, I can see no reference to any of the email certificates within certlm.msc.